# Segue not being performed ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I've got an iOS app that allows a user to connect to our server and perform a couple tasks. It works great until I decided to throw an error in and make it go back to the previous view controller. I created a segue with the Identifier of "segShowError" that is supposed to be executed and send the user back to the parent screen. Currently the segue is a Modal, as is the one that goes from the first controller to the second one. The odd part is I was experiencing this same difficulty earlier when I was using a push segue and I fixed it by using a Modal instead. Here is the code that "should" be performing the segue.

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if(error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error was %@",error);
    return;
}
else if([data length] <= 0)
{
    NSLog(@"No data received, going back");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segShowError" sender:self];
}
```

And then I have a prepareForSegue method, it will determine what error message to send back to the parent, but right now just logs a message.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Preparing for segue");
}
```

My output

> 2012-03-21 13:14:39.148 SSPColorImprov[17401:f803] No data received, going back
>
> 2012-03-21 13:14:39.149 SSPColorImprov[17401:f803] Preparing for segue

I would think that those two messages would indicate that the segue is being performed, but I could be wrong.

There are no errors logged, no warnings in the project, and no exceptions thrown. Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly... you want the segue to dismiss the modal view controller?

Comment: Essentially yes, but I wasn't aware that was an option, I guess that makes sense though

Comment: Well, don't rush, because you can't dimiss a view with segue. The view that is presented modally, needs to dismiss itself. I was just asking to better understand your question.

Comment: @Canopus I don't necessarily need a segue to do it, that's just the way that made the most sense to me, but a controller dismissing itself would work as well

Comment: right. so I think you need to replace [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segShowError" sender:self]; with -dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Comment: Would you post that as an answer so I can accept it? That worked great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dismiss a view that is presented modally, you need to dismiss it by calling 
`- dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` rather than using segues. e.g.

> ```
> // used to be dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: but deprecated in iOS 5
> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
> ```